# SVG path bezier curve

Tags: svg

I am trying to create a shape to match the image bubble, however I cannot seem to get it smooth fitting the edges.
[image: Image without line]

[image: Bubble]

I have tried using quadratic and cubic with multiple coordinates.

Please see my codepen:

https://codepen.io/kirnc/pen/QWvLBNY

```
<html>
    <head>
<style>
img
{
    width:800px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9;

}

svg
{
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
}


</style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="test">
        <img src="https://e-bug.eu/images/backgrounds/testshape2.png" />

        <svg>
        <path d="M320,15 
        C240,25 70,50 50,250
        C70,530 475,530 680,420
        C885,260 750,110 690,110
        C490,120  500,110 470,100
        C420,60 420,60 420,60
        Q390,20 320,15 
                    
        " 
        style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:3;fill:none;" />
    </svg>
</div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating the path by hand?  You will have better luck if you load the image into a vector editor (Illustrator, Inkscape, etc) and use its drawing tools to make your path.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I dont know if I should thank you or hate you haha......... Ive spent 5 days trying to get the exact shape and you have just shown me how to export it. You are a legend. Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

below SVG will work just change the size as per your needs

```
 <svg width="3958" height="2905" viewBox="0 0 3958 2905" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3958 0H0V2905H3958V0ZM1510 85.5C1062.83 119.5 183.6 421.4 244 1357C306.833 1683.83 635.1 2348.3 1445.5 2391.5C2106.33 2459.67 3506.7 2385.9 3821.5 1545.5C3934.83 1206.17 3976.1 531.8 3234.5 549C2942.83 591.667 2314 606.5 2132 324.5C2025.33 226.996 1751.6 42.6899 1510 85.5Z" fill="#FF0000"/>
</svg>
```